# Bouncing ball javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an html page that has buttons for bouncing the ball, I want to ball to start in the middle when the page is loaded which is what it does. Then i want it to bounce when I push the button called bounce yet, when i click it it only moves 1 frame. Id like it to just keep bouncing.

html code

```
 <button type="button" onclick="bounce()">Bounce</button>
```

javascript function for the ball when button is clicked

```
var canvas;
var ctx;
var ballX = 250;
var ballY = 250;
var xVelocity = 2;
var yVelocity = 3;
var ballWidth = 50;

 //Gets Canvas + Sets Framerate
 window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("test");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 setInterval(draw,1000/60);
}

//Draw EVERYTHING
function draw() {

//Color The Canvas white
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

//Draw The Ball
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.arc(ballX,ballY,ballWidth,0,Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

}

//Change Ball Position
function bounce()
{

 ballX += xVelocity;
 ballY += yVelocity;

 if(ballX - ballWidth <= 0) {
  xVelocity = -xVelocity;

}

//Bounce Ball Off Right 
if(ballX + ballWidth >= canvas.width) {
xVelocity = -xVelocity;

}

 //Bounce Ball Off Top
if(ballY - ballWidth <= 0) {
 yVelocity = -yVelocity;

}

//Bounce Ball Off Bottom 
if(ballY + ballWidth >= canvas.height) {
  yVelocity = -yVelocity;

}

}
```

Comment: Your `bounce()` is what moves the ball. Calling it once will move the ball by a few pixels. It sounds like you want the ball to start moving when you click the button? In that case you need to a) set the initial velocities to zero b) `bounce()` the ball every frame, like `draw()` c) set the velocities to something other than zero when you click the button: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/w2km0x47/

Answer (score 0):

your problem is because you need run bounce inside draw function, you need a flag to activate this function.

```
<button type="button" onclick="bounceFlag= true;">Bounce</button>

var bounceFlag = false;
```

and inside of draw

```
if(bounceFlag) {
    bounce()
}
```

you can see your example working here [https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQeRxM?editors=1010][